# How to merge maps and get a map of lists?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

Let's say we a list of maps. Maps all have the same keywords, but we don't know the keywords beforehand.

```
[{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4}]
```

And what would be the idiomatic way of merging this list into such a map:

```
{:a [1 3]
 :b [2 4]}
```

Doesn't seem hard, however as I start to implement the function, it gets super ugly and repetitive. I have a feeling that there are much cleaner ways of achieving this.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually get a pretty elegant solution by using several functions from the standard library:

```
(defn consolidate [& ms]
  (apply merge-with conj (zipmap (mapcat keys ms) (repeat [])) ms))
```

Example:

```
(consolidate {:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4})
;=> {:a [1 3], :b [2 4]}
```

One cool thing about this solution is that it works even if the maps have different key sets.

Comment: That is a pretty short solution, but I couldn't understand it until I tried each little piece in the REPL.  `mapcat` is quite useful there.

Comment: Looks great even though the argument type is different: [ms] vs [& ms]. Is there a way to spread the ms list as arguments instead when calling consolidate?

Comment: Oguz - See my rewrite of Sam's solution.

Comment: @OguzBilgic Yes; you can either change the argument vector to just `[ms]` or use [`apply`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply): `(apply consolidate [{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4}])`

Answer (score 4):

i would rather use double reduction to "merge" them with `update`:

```
(defn merge-maps-with-vec [maps]
  (reduce (partial reduce-kv #(update %1 %2 (fnil conj []) %3))
          {} maps))

user> (merge-maps-with-vec [{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4 :c 10}])
{:a [1 3], :b [2 4], :c [10]}
```

It is not as expressive as @Sam Estep's answer, but on the other hand it doesn't generate any intermediate sequences (like every-key-to-empty-vector map which also needs one extra pass through every entry of every map). Of course, premature optimizations are bad in general, but it won't hurt here i guess. Though the `reduce` based solution looks a bit more obscure, but being put into a library with proper docs it would not look as obscure to the end user (or to yourself a year after)

Answer (score 0):

While many solutions are possible, here is one that uses some of the convenience functions [in the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo):

```
(ns clj.core
  (:use tupelo.core)
  (:require [tupelo.schema :as ts]
            [schema.core :as s] ))

(s/defn gather-keys
  [list-of-maps :- [ts/KeyMap]]
  (newline)
  (let [keys-vec (keys (first list-of-maps))]
    (s/validate [s/Keyword] keys-vec) ; verify it is a vector of keywords
    (apply glue
      (for [curr-key keys-vec]
        {curr-key (forv [curr-map list-of-maps]
                    (get curr-map curr-key))} ))))
(deftest t-maps
  (spyx
    (gather-keys [{:a 1 :b 2}
                  {:a 3 :b 4} ] )))

(gather-keys [{:a 1, :b 2} {:a 3, :b 4}]) ;=> {:a [1 3], :b [2 4]}
```

Note that this solution *assumes* that each input map has an identical set of keys. Normally I'd want to enforce that assumption with a sanity check in the code as well.

Looking at the answer from Sam, I would rewrite it with some temporary variables to help document the sub-steps:

```
(defn consolidate-keys [list-of-maps]
  (let [keys-set     (set (mapcat keys list-of-maps))
        base-result  (zipmap keys-set  (repeat [] )) ]
    (apply merge-with conj base-result list-of-maps)))

(consolidate-keys  [ {:a 1 :b 2}
                     {:a 3 :z 9} ] )
;=> {:z [9], :b [2], :a [1 3]}
```

Comment: I already accepted his answer, but thank you for the rewrite, easier to understand.

Comment: Why do you include your `tupelo` library in every answer? It just makes it harder for anyone to actually use your code, and typically does not lead to any better solution.

Comment: I didn't intend my solution to be a "trick answer"... I apologize if it caused any confusion.

Comment: Sam: I rarely see `mapcat` or `zipmap` used, so I always have to stop & puzzle out what is really going on, esp. in this instance since `mapcat` generates many duplicate keys that `zipmap` automagically de-duped. That was quite a head-scratcher until I prototyped it in the repl.

Comment: @AlanThompson OK, that makes sense, but the fact that you are unfamiliar with `mapcat` and `zipmap` does *not* make my answer a "trick answer". I would prefer you not to misrepresent it as such.

Comment: Sam: I did not mean it in a bad way, but more like "high-performance"  (e.g. "a nice trick" or "a tricked out race engine").

Comment: @AlanThompson Ah, I misunderstood your intent, sorry. Thank you for editing your post. :)